# Answer awarded bounty but not accepted as an answer. Bounty not added to reputation

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, accepted-answer

I've answered a question with a bounty.

Ultimately the question author found out the solution by himself, posted it and accepted that answer. But they decided to award my answer a bounty for my effort and help. Unfortunately, the bounty has not been added to my reputation.

Here is the question in case:
[django-filter messing around with empty field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52575054/9820085)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually *has* been added to [your reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9820085/kamil-niski?tab=reputation):

[image]

FWIW, bounties are completely independent from accepting an answer.